# a ssh issue when tried to rebuild a node.js image with drone.io

Tags: docker, drone.io

I am just installing drone inside of my AWS server with the docker pre-installed. I have configured the drone and link to my github application. Everything works fine.

At last, I made a private repository in the github and wanted to use drone to build the image. This repository is a node.js application uisng mongodb, redis, rabbitmq, and on the top of repository I included the yml

```
image: bradrydzewski/node:0.10
env:
     // no idea what to configure ??
script:
     // what kind of script I should put here, bash script to build the image in aws ??
services:
  - mongodb
  - rabbitmq
  - redis
notify:
  email:
    recipients:
      - lunask@gmail.com
```

in this yml, I don't know how to configure env and script. what I should add to enable this simple node.js application. is these script used to configure the custom docker image ?

so I just reuse the offical images from drone group

```
docker pull bradrydzewski/ubuntu
docker pull bradrydzewski/base
# node images
docker pull bradrydzewski/node:0.10        # image node0.10
```

after all of these, so I commit to my github, then the drone receive this commit notification, and rebuild the image for this application.

but in the process of rebuilding, a error popped up

```
Now using node v0.10.22
$ git clone --depth=50 --recursive --branch=master git@github.com:helxsz/food.git /var/cache/drone/src/github.com/helxsz/food
Cloning into '/var/cache/drone/src/github.com/helxsz/food'...
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

don't know what is wrong with the problem
P.S I have added the ssh sent from drone to github repository

Answer (score 0):

does this help: http://dannytsang.co.uk/docker-on-digitalocean-cannot-resolve-hostnames/ ? Apparently docker cannot resolv hostnames with IPv6 nameservers

What worked for me was commenting the IPv6 nameservers in `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND — YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
#nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8844
#nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8888
nameserver 209.244.0.3
```

(and then seupt the dhcp to use non IPv6 nameservers)